# XGBoost Convergence Plot with Sklearn Wrapper

Tags: python, xgboost, gbm, convergence

I am using the sklearn wrapper for xgboost.  I would like to generate a plot of AUC for both my train and test samples for each iteration as shown in the plot below.

In sklearn you can use `warm_start` to iterate one at a time so you can easily stop to evaluate performance.  Is there a way to do the same thing using the xgboost sklearn wrapper?

[image: convergence plot]